# display text and image in single line

Tags: html, css

[image]

we are using below code to display text in one line and image in below line.

what i tried is `position : relative: top: xxpx; bottom: xxpx;` but i think its bad way of coding.

[image]

**html**

```
<div class="cc51">
   <?php echo $this->__('Add/Change Background color'); ?>
   <div class="cc55"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/circle.PNG') ?>" alt="image upload button" /></div>
   <br/>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.cc51 {
     margin-top: 40px;
     font-size: 24px;
}
.cc55 {

}
```

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: @LGSon Thanks a lot..... i found solution.

Comment: Am asking as flexbox won't work on older browsers

Comment: @LGSon it should support for older versions too. can you please help me for which answer is better in below answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way if you need to support older browsers is simply like this, where the `white-space: nowrap;` keep them in 1 line even on smaller screen sizes

```css
.cc51 {
  font-size: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.cc55 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc51">                  
  Add/Change Background color
  <div class="cc55"><img src="http://placehold.it/35/f00" alt="image upload button"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you could drop the inner `div`

```css
.cc51 {
  font-size: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.cc51 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc51">                  
  Add/Change Background color
  <img src="http://placehold.it/35/f00" alt="image upload button"/>  
</div>
```

Even the `img` could be dropped

```css
.cc51 {
  font-size: 24px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.cc51:after {
  content: url(http://placehold.it/35/f00);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc51">                  
  Add/Change Background color
</div>
```

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe Added 2 more samples, with a cleaner markup

Answer (score 3):

Just add **inline-flex**

```
cc51{
   display:inline-flex;
 }
```

use above code in your css or you can use below css

or you can also use below css.

```
     .cc51{
       float:left;
     }
     .cc55{
       float:right;
     }
     .cc54{
        clear:both;
     }
```

Comment: please check here also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719035/display-dropdown-menu-items-in-next-column

Answer (score 1):

You can either use (on the text element like , add class to "Add/Change Background colour")

`display: inline-block;`

Or you can float the elements to the left/right

`float: left;`

Just don't forget to clear the floats after

`clear: left;`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
.cc51
{
 margin-top: 40px;
 font-size: 24px;
 display:flex;
 align-text:center;
}
```

this way  the image will be aligned centered to the text

see here : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghrjg0tg/)**

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add following css

```
.cc51 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
}
.cc55 {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: inline-block` for both text and image to show in one line.

```css
.cc51 .text,
.cc51 .cc55 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="cc51">                  
  <div class="text">Add/Change Background color</div>
  <div class="cc55">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/circle.PNG') ?>" alt="image upload button"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I went on the site you've linked in the post and the following code works:

```
.cc55 {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: No worries, you are flooded with answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Set position (float) as per you requirement

```
cc51 img{
     display:inline; float:right; vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-flex`

```css
.cc51
 {
     display:inline-flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="cc51">                  
             Add/Change Background color          
            <div class="cc55"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/circle.PNG') ?>" alt="image upload button"/></div>
            <br/>
</div>
```